# Matching with [\S\s]*? vs (.)+ regexps

Tags: javascript, regex

I am try to match the contents between two markers `%{` and `}%` with JavaScript.

I have regular expressions that work in a regex tester, however when I put them into my code they do not work. I believe it may be an escaping issue, however I am not sure.

The following regex works, but does not allow whitespace:

```
var databinder = new RegExp("%\{(.)+\}%", 'g');
```

The following regex works in a regex tester, and allows white space, however it does not return any matchs in my code:

```
var databinder = new RegExp("%\{[\S\s]*?\}%", 'g');
```

It only works when I remove the:

```
[\S\s]*?
```

What is causing the regex to not work in the second example?

Here is an example of text I am matching:

```
<td align="right" style="width: 123px;">%{toFixedEx(#{surcharge()}#,2,4)}%</td>
<td align="right" style="width: 123px;">%{toFixedEx(#{extendedPrice()}#,2,2)}%</td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to double escape the backslashes on any special regex modifiers when using a string:

```
var databinder = new RegExp("%\\{[\\S\\s]*\\}%", 'g');
```

or you can use a regex literal:

```
var databinder = /%\{[\S\s]*?\}%/g;
```

Comment: Habitually escaping `{` doesn't hurt and it will save your from wondering why things like `'11{23}'.match(/11{23}/)` don't "work".